# No Wifi-Adapter Found on 21.04 (Lenovo Legion 7)

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I just received a new Lenovo Legion 7 and installed 20.04 LTS alongside Win 10. Wifi adapter not found. Then I replaced it with 21.04. Wifi adapter still not found. I tried disabling FastBoot in Windows and that didn't work.

Output to lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
03:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8621] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [17aa:384b]
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

I tried this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo cp  rtw8852a_fw.bin  /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

But the last command gives me this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Operation not permitted
```

This is from this page to install the driver for my wireless card: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

Comment: Have you installed the additional drivers package?

Comment: i tried this:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh   
sudo modprobe 8821ce

and this:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au/
sudo make dkms_install

to no avail.

Comment: i also just tried the instructions here to install the drivers for my wifi card:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

but the last step gives me this error: 

"modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Operation not permitted"

Comment: sorry about that. I added the most relevant comment to the main post.

Comment: Nevermind it works now! I needed to disable SecureBoot in bios to get rid of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Operation not permitted

Please disable Secure Boot in your EFI/Bios. Your wireless should then be working.