# Not working Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, lenovo

I have Lenovo Ideapad 5 with AMD Ryzen 5 CPU for around 2 months, running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit. The Wi-Fi section in settings is missing. I can't connect to the internet via internal Wi-Fi card. I have been using external Wi-Fi adapter and docking station as temporary alternative.

Output of command `uname -srm` is:

```
Linux 5.11.0-38-generic x86_64
```

Output of command `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d05fffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx909a4acb9022
       serial: 90:9a:4a:cb:90:22
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau driverversion=5.11.0-38-generic ip=192.168.1.251 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

Output of command `sudo rfkill` is:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Output of command `dkmp status` is:

```
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Output of command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:164c] (rev c2)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:164c] (rev c2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
```

I don't know which one is the correct and which not.
How can i fix this to make it works? What am I supposed to do to fix laptop Wi-fi?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` as it might be that new 8859 or whatever that needs rtw89

Comment: Outputs of commands have been added.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353650/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-21-04-lenovo-legion-7 There are install instructions in the question

Comment: Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852] @Pilot6 Jeremy was quite correct!

Comment: Thanks you all for responds. @Jeremy31 I followed the instructions in link you attached and it worked for me. Thank you for solving the issue.